# Position two sprites on a THREE.Line

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a networking diagram that illustrates the network connections between devices with a line. Ilm trying to added labels to the line on each end that illustrates the network interfaces as well.

I'm using drag controls to move the network devices around the scene and updating the line positions with the new positions. All is well here.

The issue is positioning the labels. Example:

[object]----[label/sprite]------[boundingSpere.center]-----[label/sprite]----[object]

Here is an image for reference

[Scene with Nodes links and one label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knJHh.png)

I've tried:

Created new line objects using the boundingSpere.center vector of the original line and the boundingBox min/max vectors. Then I positioned the sprite at the boundingSpere.center of the new line. This actually worked depending on the line direction.

```
        export const setLinkLabels = (linkLabelOne, linkLabelTwo, 
        multiSelect, line, position, postion2) => {

        linkLabelOne.direction = 'from'
        linkLabelOne.to = multiSelect.current[0].uuid
        linkLabelOne.position.x = position.center.x
        linkLabelOne.position.y = position.center.y


        linkLabelTwo.direction = 'to'
        linkLabelTwo.to = multiSelect.current[1].uuid
        linkLabelTwo.position.x = postion2.center.x
        linkLabelTwo.position.y = postion2.center.y

    }
    
    export const canvas = (deviceName) => {

        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 256;
        canvas.height = 256;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        if (deviceName === 'interface') {
            ctx.font = "20pt Arial"
        } else {
            ctx.font = "33pt Arial"
        }

        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 8;

        if (deviceName !== undefined) {
            ctx.strokeText(deviceName, 128, 46);
            ctx.fillText(deviceName, 128, 46);
        } else {
            ctx.strokeText('device', 128, 46);
            ctx.fillText('device', 128, 46);
        }

        return canvas

    }


    const addLink = (operation) => {
        const points = [];
        const group = new THREE.Group()
        group.isLine = true

        points.push(multiSelect.current[0].position);
        points.push(multiSelect.current[1].position);

        const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
        const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, depthTest: false});
        const line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);

        line.links = {from: multiSelect.current[0].uuid, to: multiSelect.current[1].uuid}
        line.renderOrder = 0

        line.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
        line.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
        line.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        
        let tempPoints = []
        tempPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(line.geometry.boundingBox.max.x, line.geometry.boundingBox.max.y, 0));
        tempPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(line.geometry.boundingSphere.center.x, line.geometry.boundingSphere.center.y, 0));

        const tempGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(tempPoints);
        const tempMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
        const Templine = new THREE.Line(tempGeometry, tempMaterial);

        Templine.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

        tempPoints = []
        tempPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(line.geometry.boundingBox.min.x, line.geometry.boundingBox.min.y, 0));
        tempPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(line.geometry.boundingSphere.center.x, line.geometry.boundingSphere.center.y, 0));

        const tempGeometry1 = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(tempPoints);
        const tempMaterial1 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial();
        const Templine1 = new THREE.Line(tempGeometry1, tempMaterial1);
        Templine1.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
        //
        const linkLabelOne = modifyDeviceName(multiSelect.current[0].interface, 'dynamicBuilder', multiSelect.current[0].position)
        const linkLabelTwo = modifyDeviceName(multiSelect.current[1].interface, 'dynamicBuilder', multiSelect.current[1].position)
        setLinkLabels(linkLabelOne, linkLabelTwo, multiSelect, Templine.geometry.boundingSphere, Templine1.geometry.boundingSphere)
        
        multiSelect.current.push(linkLabelOne)
        multiSelect.current.push(linkLabelTwo)
        group.add(linkLabelOne, linkLabelTwo)

    }
```

Ideas:

Create three separate lines connecting all objects.

Get the distance and the angle of the line and some how calculate the positions needed.

Comment: Please see the [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please show us the code of what you've tried.

Comment: posted the code used in the block. Only the setLinkLabels function pertains to the actual issue. I'm think there has to be a better solution even if I was to get this to work.

Comment: I don't think creating a `2d` canvas is a good solution because you'd have to manually do a lot of translating between 3D -> 2D positions. If all you want to do is add text labels, why don't you use a [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer)? It's basically a big `<div>` that sits on top of your 3d `<canvas>` so the two overlap. The renderer takes care of all the positioning via CSS. You can see [a basic example here](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label), and a more complex [example here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_pdb).